# How do I print the number of negative subarrays from a given array?

Tags: java, sub-array

**Problem Statement:**

Given an array of n integers, find and print its number of negative subarrays on a new line.(A subarray is negative if the total sum of its elements is negative.)

**Sample Input**

5

1 -2 4 -5 1

**Sample Output**

9

**Result that my code yields**

> Input (stdin)
>
> 5
>
> 1 -2 4 -5 1
>
> Your Output (stdout)
>
> 7
>
> Expected Output
>
> 9
>
> Compiler Message
>
> Wrong Answer

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        int b[] = new int[n];
        int count=0;
        int i,j,sum = 0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();            
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
        if(a[i]<0){count++;}
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
            sum = a[i] + sum;
            b[j] = sum;
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
        if(b[j]<0){count++;}
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        
    } 
}
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: what is b[] array for?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: If i understand correctly the requirement, i still wasn't able to find 9 combinations for the given input and have found only 6.
(1,-2);(4,-5);(-5,1);(-2,4,-5);(-2,4,-5,1);(1,-2,4,-5,1).
Am i missing something?

Comment: @drgPP you missed 1-2+4-5 pair

Comment: seems like -2 and -5 also considered as separate sub-arrays instead of elements

Comment: @PavneetSingh yeap, i missed that one, but, from my knowledge, by a definition, a sub-array of an array should not have gaps, i.e. it should appear in the same order as the original array.

Comment: singular elements are also consider as sub-array  so count them too and you are good to go and @drgPP you mean by -2 or -5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made few changes to the previous logic and now this code works fine.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            int a[] = new int[n];
            int count=0;
            int i,j,sum = 0;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                a[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }
            scan.close();
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                sum = 0;
                for(j=i;j<n;j++)
                {
                    sum = a[j] + sum;
                    if(sum<0){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution running in O(nlogn), based idea on counting inversion

1. calculate the prefix sum array of the given input, it contains cumulative sums
2. count the inversion in the prefix sum array when `prefix[i] > prefix[j] when i < j`, also count when `prefix[j] < 0`

the time complexity is analyzed like merge-sort

```java
import java.util.*;

public class NegativeSumSubarray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 1, -2, 4, -5, 1 };

        int[] prefixSum = new int[array.length];
        prefixSum[0] = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < prefixSum.length; i++) {
            prefixSum[i] = prefixSum[i - 1] + array[i];
        }

        int count = countInversion(prefixSum, 0, prefixSum.length - 1);
        System.out.println(count); // 9
    }

    public static int countInversion(int[] prefixSum, int left, int right) {
        // merge-sort like counting inversion in prefixSum array
        if (left == right) {
            if (prefixSum[left] < 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        int count_left = countInversion(prefixSum, left, mid);
        int count_right = countInversion(prefixSum, mid + 1, right);
        int count_cross = countCrossInversion(prefixSum, left, mid, right);
        return count_left + count_right + count_cross;
    }

    public static int countCrossInversion(int[] prefixSum, int left, int mid, int right) {
        List<Integer> L = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = left; i <= mid; i++) {
            L.add(prefixSum[i]);
        }
        L.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        List<Integer> R = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = mid + 1; i <= right; i++) {
            R.add(prefixSum[i]);
        }
        R.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int k = left; k <= right; k++) {
            if (L.get(i) <=  R.get(j)) {
                prefixSum[k] = L.get(i);
                i += 1;
            } else {
                prefixSum[k] = R.get(j);
                count += L.size() - 1 - i; // size() counts additional sentinal MAX_VALUE
                j += 1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```